# Internet Connection Sharing via Router

Tags: network-shares

My Fedora laptop is connected to Internet via USB over 3G mobile phone. If I want to share the internet connection to family over wireless LAN, what should I do?

My Fedora laptop has wireless card and LAN card.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, therefore closing this question and marked as Answered. For others benefit, share an article [here](http://blink4blog.blogspot.com/2012/02/fedora-16-post-installation-guide_20.html).